# PI-algebra linearly independent set of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra

I think this problem is reduced to simple computations/algebraic tricks, so I don't think it matters if you know PI-algebra theory, but I could be wrong, basically I want to find a nonzero polynomial such that evaluated on an algebra is always zero ($g|_A \equiv 0.$)

I'm doing a problem about PI-algebras. I'll put the definition here first:

> Definition: Let $A$ be an $F$-algebra and $f=f(x1,\dots,x_n)\in F\langle X\rangle$ nonzero. $f$ is a polynomial identity of $A$ if $f(a_1,\dots,a_n)=0$ for all $a_1,...,a_n\in A$. $A$ is called a PI-algebra.

Now, my problem is:

> Let $f_i(ξ_1,\dots, ξ_n) \in F\langle X \rangle$, $i = 1, \dots,m$, be linearly independent polynomials. Show that an $F$-algebra $A$ must be a PI-algebra if for arbitrary $x_1,\dots, x_n\in  A$ the evaluations $f_i(x_1,\dots, x_n),$ $i = 1, \dots,m$, are linearly dependent in $A$.

That means that I have to find $g\in K\langle X \rangle$ such that $g|_A \equiv 0.$

Now, the problem gives us a set of linearly independent polynomials so I'm guessing the polynomial identity that $A$ satisfies is something like $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m \alpha_if_i,$ with $\alpha_i\in F$ for every $i=1,\dots,m$ since it would never be the zero polynomial unless every $\alpha_i=0,$  but I'm not sure how to obtain those escalars. I tried saying $f_1$ must be linear combination of the rest polynomials, but it did not get me anywhere.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Edit: There is a technique in PI-algebras and it is linealization. That means we get a polynomial identity and we start transforming it in a polynomial that the degree of each unkown in each monomial is $1.$ I was trying to change $f_i$ to a $g_i$ that satisfies what I just say.

**Second edit**

Alright, the wording of the problem is rather ambiguous and we have two ways to understand it. The first is, pointed by Paul in the comments, that $\{f_i |_A\}$ is dependent over $A.$

The second way is that taking any $n$-tuple of elements of $A,$ $(a_1,\dots,a_n),$ the set $\{f_i(a_1,\dots,a_n)\}$ is linearly dependent in $A.$ I'm not sure how to get to a polynomial such that is a polynomial identity for $A.$ However, I came across to this result:

> $f\in K\langle X\rangle$ is an PI for an algebra $A,$ if and only if, $f\in \bigcap\limits_{\varphi: K\langle X\rangle \rightarrow A} \text{Ker } \varphi,$ where $\varphi$ is an isomorphism of algebras.

I think I can use this result but I'm not sure, I'll update if I'm able to get anything from this.

Comment: You're right. I was thinking of $F\langle X \rangle$ as being functions from $X\to F$, but that isn't correct. I've deleted the answer.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Don't worry, thanks so much for trying to help me. I really appreciate it. If you can give it another try at my question, it would be really helpful.

Comment: It's possible that even though my reasons for thinking it were incorrect, my interpretation of that curious phrasing was still the intention. I.e. that they mean the restrictions $f_i|_{A^n}$ are linearly dependent. If so, then my conclusion is still correct: there exist $\{\alpha_i\}$ with $F = \sum \alpha_if_i = 0$ on $A$, but $F \ne 0$ in $F\langle X \rangle$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair You are probably right, thanks. Now I'm wondering if the other case is true as well.